# How to get beacon's distance in meters?

Tags: javascript, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I need to create a small prototype using beacons and to display the distance to each beacon in meters. At the moment I can only see which is the closest one but need to display as well how far is the device from the beacon.

So my question is "How to get distance to a beacon in meters. Is there any code snippets, examples, samples?".

I now there are a lot of articles about beacons, unstable RSSI and that you cannot get the exact distance from a beacon.
But I saw some examples with indoor location and how beacons perfectly work.

By the way, my app is built using javascript and html. It is not an Android app yet.

Comment: How are you using javascript and html to detect beacons now?  Are you using a Cordova plugin, a Chrome extension or something else?

Comment: @davidgyoung I use EvoThings work bench to detect beacons. So I need an example or a piece of code that would display the distance in meters.

Comment: Are you using this plugin?  https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons/blob/master/documentation.md

Comment: @davidgyoung I use another example but very similar to this one. But there is nothing about how to get distance in meters.